# How to share value based on availability in database

Tags: php

I've been thinking if this is possible. Is there a way I can get the value of an input field from a form, and split or share this value among some receivers stored in my database?

Let's say the user entered $10, and I want to share this amount to some users stored in the database who want to receive $7 and $3 respectively.

The issue for me now is that these values are not static, they change. I cannot really determine the amount that a user will enter in the form, and the amount that the stored users want to receive too varies.

How do I come up with an algorithm such that:

- it checks the amount the user entered,
- keeps sharing it among the receivers, until no receiver again OR amount is exhausted?

This is the code I've written so far... I'll just add what's necessary here:

```
//function to get users from database
function getUsers() {
    $users = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `status` = 'receiver'");
    if ( $users->count() ) {
        return $users->results();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//then the process
$enteredAmount = Input::get('amount'); //from the form
if ( getUsers() ) {
    $users = getUsers();
//this is where I am stuck. don't know what to do from here
}
```

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Comment: Does the amount of receivers vary? Also, do all the receivers determine the amount they want to receive? No matter what, you will need to calculate the total amount of what the receivers want and see if that's less or equal to the amount paid. If it's less, what happens to the left over? If it's more, you need to handle it. All in all there's a lot of questions that need to be answered.

Comment: Yes, the number of receivers vary as there can be more than one receiver, and the amount they want to receive is stored in the database, and that varies too. What I want to do is if the amount is equal or less than the amount of the first result (user), then pay that user only. But if the amount is greater, pay the first user, then proceed to the next user with the left over, and so on.

Comment: In that case it shouldn't be too hard. You save the amount paid in a variable. Then you create a loop that loops through the array where you saved all users. On each loop, you check if the amount the receiver wants is equal er smaller than the amount paid. If so, subtract and add to receiver amount. If not, add what's left over to the users account and break away from the loop.

Comment: I have written an example code for you here. You should easily be able to adept it for your own code. Click Run on the website to see the results: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m25v-u4ub

Comment: Thanks @icecub, your code worked perfectly. I should be able to edit it to suit my own code.

Comment: You're welcome :) Have fun with it!